# Pandas: Calculating a Z-score to avoid "look ahead" bias

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have time series data in dataframe named "df", and, my code for calculating the z-score is given below:

```
mean = df.mean()
standard_dev = df.std()
z_score = (df - mean) / standard_dev
```

I would like to calculate the z-score for each observation using the respective observation and data that was known at the point of recording the observation. i.e. I **do not** want to use a standard deviation and mean that incorporates data that occurs after a specific point in time. I just want to use data from time ***t, t-1, t-2....***

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign two new columns, containing the mean and std of previous items. I here assume, that your time series data is in the column 'time_series_data':

```
len_ = len(df)
df['mean_past'] = [np.mean(df['time_series_data'][0:lv+1]) for lv in range(len_)]
df['std_past'] = [np.std(df['time_series_data'][0:lv+1]) for lv in range(len_)]
df['z_score'] = (df['time_series_data'] - df['mean_past']) / df['std_past']
```

**Edit**: if you want to z-score all columns, you could define a function, that computes the z-score and apply it on all columns of your dataframe:

```
def z_score_column(column):
    len_ = len(column)
    mean = [np.mean(column[0:lv+1]) for lv in range(0,len_)]
    std =  [np.std(column[0:lv+1]) for lv in range(0,len_)]
    return [(c-m)/s for c,m,s in zip(column, mean, std)]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10,5))
df.apply(z_score_column)
```

Comment: @ Arco Bast: Assuming that I wish to do the exercise for the whole dataframe--it's entirely made up of with timeseries data--would the procedure be: len_ = len(df)
df_mean = [np.mean(df[0:lv]) for lv in range(len_)]
df_std = [np.std(df[0:lv]) for lv in range(len_)]
df_z_score = df - df_mean / df_std

Answer (score 1):

Use `.expanding()` - `col` being the column you want to compute your statistics for (drop `[col]` in case, if you wish to compute it for the whole dataframe):

You might need to sort values by time column first - denoted as `time_col` (in case if it's not sorted already):

```py
df=df.sort_values("time_col", axis=0)
```

Then:

```py
df[col].sub(df[col].expanding().mean()).div(df[col].expanding().std())
```

Ref:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html

For the sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({"a": list("xyzpqrstuv"), "b": [6,5,7,1,-9,0,3,5,2,8]})

df["c"]=df["b"].sub(df["b"].expanding().mean()).div(df["b"].expanding().std())
```

Outputs:

```py
   a  b         c
0  x  6       NaN
1  y  5 -0.707107
2  z  7  1.000000
3  p  1 -1.425880
4  q -9 -1.677484
5  r  0 -0.281450
6  s  3  0.210502
7  t  5  0.534207
8  u  2 -0.046142
9  v  8  1.062430
```